# Dex Data on BinanceSmartChain

Tags: websocket, bsc

I'm trying to get access to some data on the BSC using a websocket and the same methods as web3.

I've sucessfully sent the following to get the latest swap pairs created at the PancakeSwap Factory:

```
{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":1,\"method\":\"eth_getLogs\",\"params\":[{\"fromBlock\":\"0x6a54cb\",\"toBlock\":\"latest\",\"topics\":[\"0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9\"],\"address\":\"0xbcfccbde45ce874adcb698cc183debcf17952812\"}]}
```

How can I get a stream of newly-created pairs rather than specifying a start and end block? I've had no success with anything like the following:

```
{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\", \"id\": 1, \"method\": \"eth_subscribe\", \"params\": [\"logs\",{\"address\":\"0xbcfccbde45ce874adcb698cc183debcf17952812\", \"topics\":[\"0x0d3648bd0f6ba80134a33ba9275ac585d9d315f0ad8355cddefde31afa28d0e9\"]}]}
```

Would appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: What code are you using? How do you connect with websocket? Which client are you using?

Comment: Using C#. Connecting to an Ankr node. Just using a C# websocket client.